# Cordova Video Editor Plugin InvalidOutputFormatException

Tags: android, cordova, video

I'm using [cordova-plugin-video-editor](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-video-editor) to process a previous recorded video.

The plugin starts to convert but for any reason it fails:

[image: Image of the video, the start conversion and the fail]

The error that I get is this:

```
net.ypresto.androidtranscoder.engine.InvalidOutputFormatException: Non-baseline AVC video profile is not supported by Android OS, actual profile_idc: 100
```

Looking more deeper into the issue/plugin, I've realiced about a possible [bug](https://github.com/jbavari/cordova-plugin-video-editor/issues/94).

Here bellow I paste the code:

```
recordStory: function (callback) {

  var options = {
    limit: 1,
    duration: 60,
    quality: 0
  };

  document.addEventListener("deviceready", function () {
    $cordovaCapture.captureVideo(options).then(function (videoData) { // Success! Video data is here
      $timeout(function () {
        VideoEditor.transcodeVideo(function (success) {
          console.log(success);
        }, function (error) {
          console.log(error);
        }, {
          fileUri: videoData[0].fullPath, // the path to the video on the device
          outputFileName: 'encoded1', // the file name for the transcoded video
          outputFileType: VideoEditorOptions.OutputFileType.MPEG4,
          optimizeForNetworkUse: VideoEditorOptions.OptimizeForNetworkUse.YES,
          saveToLibrary: true,
          maintainAspectRatio: true,
          width: 640,
          height: 640,
          videoBitrate: 1000000, // 1 megabit
          audioChannels: 2,
          audioSampleRate: 44100,
          audioBitrate: 128000, // 128 kilobits
          progress: function (info) {
            console.log('transcodeVideo progress callback, info: ' + info);
          }
        });
        callback(null, videoData);
      }, 100);
    }, function (err) { // An error occurred. Show a message to the user
      callback(err);
    });
  }, false);
}
```

**config.xml**

```
<platform name="android">
    <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="18" />
</platform>
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-video-editor" spec="~1.1.2" />
<engine name="android" spec="~5.2.2" />
```

could anybody help here?

Thanks in advice.

Comment: are you able to solved it?