# transcoding video from ionic video editor is not working on android nougat and oreo

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

This has also asked in: [Cordova Video Editor Plugin InvalidOutputFormatException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39860809/cordova-video-editor-plugin-invalidoutputformatexception)

The error showing up is:

> net.ypresto.androidtranscoder.engine.InvalidOutputFormatException:
>   Non-baseline AVC video profile is not supported by Android OS, actual
>   profile_idc: 100

I appreciate suggestions.

Comment: https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-video-editor-issue/125836/3